# Android Intent inside switch case

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to launch an intent inside a switch case.

To check the values, I have inserted a Toast that shows the received code.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(CitaServicio_Foto_1.this, String.valueOf(requestCode),

                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode){
                case RQS_LOADIMAGE:
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    arrayUri.add(imageUri);
                    myFileListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case RQS_SENDEMAIL:
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, WelcomeNoLogin.class);
                    this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The values for the codes are:

```
final int RQS_LOADIMAGE = 0;
final int RQS_SENDEMAIL = 1;
```

The displayed toast message is 1 for RQS_SENDEMAIL, but the activity WelcomeNoLogin isn't launched.

Any help is welcome

Comment: this.startActivity(myIntent); remove this. from here and try

Comment: do you define `WelcomeNoLogin` activity in your manifest? what is your error in logcat?

Comment: @ramineftekhari, there is no error and the activity is in the manifest, after sending the email, the toast message is "1" and the current activity is shown, activity WelcomeNoLogin is not launched.

Comment: also check your `resultCode` in toast. maybe your resultCode is not RESULT_OK

Comment: @ramineftekhari, the toast message is "1" as expected

Comment: you show `requestCode` in toast. please show `requestCode` and `resultCode ` in your toast.

Comment: @ramineftekhari, the switch case condition is about requestCode

Comment: you say no error occur. so it think problem is before your switch case. you check `resultcCode` before switch. i think `resultCode` in NOT `RESULT_OK` and your switch case never run!

Comment: please remove `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)` and try again!

Comment: @ramineftekhari, I will check the received resultCode and tell you

Comment: @ramineftekhari, when requestCode = 0, then resultCode =-1, when requestCode =1, then resultCode = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [RESULT_OK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK), the RESULT_OK is -1 and your if statement is equal to false and your switch case not run.

check `setResult` of your launched activity

EDIT:

RESULT_OK = -1
RESULT_CANCELED = 0

Comment: Thank you, after removing if (resultCode == RESULT_OK), it works